# C++ partial specialization with multiple optional parameters

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

Try a partial specialization with multiple parameters. Sounds like

```
template <class T, int E=0>
class Info
{
public:
  Info& operator=(double rhs);
  T data;
};


template<int E> Info<std::string, E> &Info<std::string, E>::operator=(double rhs) {
    data = rhs;
    return *this;
}
```

But cannot compile and get

```
error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class
info<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, E>'  template<int E>
Info<std::string, E> &Info<std::string, E>::operator=(double rhs)...
```

**Update**
It seems that it is not possible to do partial spec. with multiple parameters (optional or not...) Am I wrong ?

Comment: in ur specialization, u write template<>, since the type is clear from the rest

Comment: You cannot partial specialize a function/method.

Comment: [Here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/99387ed89c73bc7e) is an example of how you could partially specialize the class to then in turn have a specialized member function.